# How do I use InterruptibleChannel?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a thread in Android that will use Bluetooth communication. I want the thread to be interruptible even when blocking on I/O, so it seems [InterruptibleChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) is a good solution. My question is what should the code look like? What I have so far doesn't seem to send anything. Here it is:

```
this.outstream = Channels.newChannel(outstream);
this.outstream.write(message);
```

Where `outstream` is an OutputStream I derived from the Bluetooth socket.

Comment: I'm not following your question.  Where are you expecting the interrupt to originate from?  And what do you want to happen if/when the interrupt occurs?

Comment: My motivation is that I want `outstream` and `instream` to time out after a certain period. Since there's no mechanism for doing that what I'm doing is spawning a thread which receives `outstream` and `instream` from the main thread. Then, if that thread hangs on read or write the main thread will interrupt it, causing the streams to stop whatever it is they're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the timer thread you mentioned in your comments that's going to interrupt the channel after a certain amount of time, there are two cases you need to handle, each of which has its own checked exception:

- Case 1 : Another thread invoked `close()` on the channel while your thread is blocked on an I/O operation.  Your call to `write` will abort with an `AsynchronousCloseException`.
- Case 2 : Another thread called `interrupt()` on your thread while it's blocking on an I/O operation.  Your call to `write()` will abort with a `ClosedByInterruptException`.

You would want to update your code to handle those exceptions:

```
this.outstream = Channels.newChannel(outstream);
try {
    outstream.write(message);
}
catch(AsynchronousCloseException e) {
    System.out.println("Another thread closed the stream while this one was blocking on I/O!");
}
catch(ClosedByInterruptException e) {
    System.out.println("This thread has been interrupted while blocking on I/O!");
}
```

Take care to notice that the contract of `InterruptibleChannel` specifies that these exceptions will only be thrown *if the current thread is blocked in an I/O operation*.  If your thread *isn't* blocking, then neither of these exceptions will be thrown.  In that case, it's likely that if another thread closed the channel you'd get a different IOException for trying to write to a closed channel, and if you're not paying attention to the current thread's interrupted status, it will keep writing.  However, since behavior for that case is not specified by the interface, it's up to the implementor to decide what to do.